# How can I limit memory usage for a C++ code via command line using gcc?

Tags: c++

How can I limit memory usage for a C++ code via command line using gcc?

For context, I'm implementing a code judge so I need to run every script students submit, I was able to do the same for Java with the following command:

```
java -Xmx<memoryLimit> Main
```

So far no luck with gcc, any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: On Linux you can use `cgroups` for many configurations. I'm not sure if you can limit memory but you can check it.

Comment: You need to use an OS specific feature that allows you to limit the memory usage of a program. I don't think compilers can limit the memory usage of programs.

Comment: I want to limit the memory ram usage, I don't want the students to kill the server by "mistake"

Comment: Use a docker container for each submission and limit its memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much that the compiler can do in regard to limit the memory use of a program.

Programs are generally not run within a "C++ virtual machine" that would be analogous to the JVM, so there is no comparable command line options for an executable.

Typically however, operating systems do support specifying resource limits of processes. To find out how, see the documentation of the operating system in which you run the  program.

---

If you use a POSIX operating system, there is `ulimit` command which can set limits to processes of a user.

If you use Linux, there are *cgroup*s, which can be used to set limits for process groups. *cgroup*s can be a bit intimidating to use, and there is a higher level way to manage them: Containers. Other operating systems have similar features such as *jail*s in FreeBSD.